# How to store all checked items from a list into the local storage. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, checkbox, local-storage

I have a list whit a dynamically created checkbox inputs and when the list is done and you finish using it, I want to store the checked items from the list to the localstorage.

(I need to store only the checked items when the save button is pressed.)

HTML:

```
<template id = "index.html">
                <ons-page id=tab1>
                <div id="listac">LISTA</div>
                <ons-list id="products">
                    <!-- HERE IS WHERE I ADD THE CHECKBOX ITEMS-->
                </ons-list>

                <ons-speed-dial position="bottom right" direction="left">
                <ons-fab>
                  <ons-icon icon="fa-cog"></ons-icon>
                </ons-fab>
                <ons-speed-dial-item ONCLICK="savefunction()"> <!--THIS IS THE BUTTON THAT "SAVES".-->
                  <ons-icon id = "consolidar"  icon="fa-cart-arrow-down"></ons-icon>
                </ons-speed-dial-item>
                <ons-speed-dial-item >
                  <ons-icon id = "anadir" icon="fa-plus" ></ons-icon>
                </ons-speed-dial-item>
                </ons-speed-dial>

                </ons-page>
            </template>
```

Js:

```
function add_checkbox_item(){

  var product = document.getElementById('addirp').value;
  var text_product = document.createTextNode(product);
  var checkbox_product = document.createElement('ons-checkbox')
  checkbox_product.appendChild(text_product);
  var finall_product = document.createElement('ons-list-item');
  finall_product.appendChild(checkbox_product);
  finall_product.classList.add("products");

  document.getElementById('productos').appendChild(finall_product);

  dialog = document.getElementById('dialog1'); 
  dialog.hide();  

}; 

function savefunction(){
  // HERE IS WHERE I START GETTING LOST

  var checkedValue = null; 
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('products');
  for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
    if(inputElements[i].checked){
      checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
      break;  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Not quite sure what you want to achieve. Am I right in that you want to store the value of each individual checkbox to the `localStorage` as soon as it is checked? Or do you want to store the values of all checkboxes once the user clicks a button or something? Asked the other way around: _When_ do you want to store the value(s)/which user interaction triggers a save? **EDIT** Also, please add your HTML to the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, i need to make something like a shopping list so you must be able to add items (that will appear in the list as checkbox) that you "will check" when you have them. After that when you press the save button, it must store only checked values. So yes it will be like you say  "... want to store the values of checked checkboxes once the user clicks a button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, is to query all the checkbox elements and iterate through them. Your code currently selects the `ons-list-item` elements instead of the checkboxes.

First, start by making the function select the correct elements:

```
function savefunction(){
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.products'); // <-- select the checkboxes
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i += 1) { // <-- iterate
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      // store values  
    } else { // <-- this branch is optional (I don't know if you need it)
      // remove previously stored values
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I also added an `else` branch, in case you also want to *remove* a previously stored value when the user *unchecks* a previously checked checkbox. However, if you don't need it, just remove the `else` branch.

From here on, you have two possibilities: You can *either* store each checked checkbox separately into the `localStorage`, *or* you can store a list of all the checked checkboxes.

**Each box separately** *(remember to remove the `else` branch if you don't need it)*

```
function savefunction(){
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.products');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i += 1) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      localStorage.setItem(checkbox[i].name, checkbox[i].value); // <-- stores a value
    } else {
      if (localStorage.getItem(checkbox[i].name)) { // <-- check for existance
        localStorage.removeItem(checkbox[i].name); // <-- remove a value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**A list of all boxes**

```
function savefunction(){
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.products');
  var checked = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i += 1) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checked[checkbox[i].name] = checkbox[i].value;
    }
    // <-- no need for else, because we simply override
  }
  localStorage.setItem('checked_boxes', JSON.stringify(checked)); // <-- localStorage can only store `String` values
}
```

When using the second approach, don't forget to call `JSON.parse` on the stored values when you want to use them (this is just for demo purposes):

```
function restoreCheckboxes (checkboxElements) {
  var checkboxStates = localStorage.getItem('checked_boxes'),
      i;
  if (checkboxStates) {
    checkboxStates = JSON.parse(checkboxStates); // <-- parse string to object
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i += 1) {
      if (checkboxStates.hasOwnProperty(checkboxElements[i].name)) {
        checkboxElements[i].checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another point is this: Do you want to persist that information *between different sessions* or just as long as *the current session is active*? If the latter is true, consider using `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. You can read about their differences [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 0):

This code will exactly be working.

Make unique the checkboxes with name parameters.
On-click call function
First function to store the values and second function to restore the values from local storage

```js
function savefunction(){

  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.products');

  var checked = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i += 1) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checked[checkboxes[i].name] = checkboxes[i].value;
    }
    // <-- no need for else, because we simply override
  }
  localStorage.setItem('checked_boxes', JSON.stringify(checked)); // <-- localStorage can only store `String` values

}





function restoreCheckboxes () {

  var checkboxElements = document.querySelectorAll('.products');
  var checkboxStates = localStorage.getItem('checked_boxes');
 
  if (checkboxStates) {
    checkboxStates = JSON.parse(checkboxStates); // <-- parse string to object
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i += 1) {
      if (checkboxStates.hasOwnProperty(checkboxElements[i].name)) {
        checkboxElements[i].checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="restoreCheckboxes()">
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
     iWork for iColud 
  </div>  
<div class="box3">
<input type="checkbox" name="bixby1"  onclick="savefunction()" class="products">
</div></div>


<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
     iWork for iColud 
  </div>  
<div class="box3">
<input type="checkbox" name="bixby2" onclick="savefunction()" class="products">
</div></div>

<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
     iWork for iColud 
  </div>  
<div class="box3">
<input type="checkbox" name="bixby3" onclick="savefunction()" class="products">
</div></div>



</body>
```